# Unable to login to SQL server, using Microsoft server studio

Tags: python, sql-server

I have an instance of SQL server running. I am perfectly able to login and perform CRUD operations using Python MSSQL library. When I am trying to connect it using Microsoft server studio 14.0 or Pycharm, I am getting error 18456. I have checked that 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication' is already activated on it. I am unable to fetch the error logs of the SQL server, as I dont have rights for it. How to connect to the server using SQL server authentication. Did I miss anything while connecting?!!

Comment: Do you have the SA account password? Is your windows account a sysadmin on the server? can you connect SSMS using the Python credentials? What rights does the Python account have?

Comment: I am not having an SA account and my windows account is not a sysadmin. The credentials that I am using through Python have Read and write rights on the server.

Comment: Sounds to me then that you need to contact the DBA/SYSAdmins of your SQL machine

Comment: i was just curious to know..how python is able to perform the operations with same user-id and password. where as SQL studio is not able to login also

Comment: Kumar it's not uncommon for your infra team to ha e gated off the access to SQL behind the firewalls